# Opentok create different tokens for users in a same session

Tags: webrtc, opentok

I am using Opentok code for my swift program. I have a question regarding tokens used.
I tried to test the app with a session id and a single token (created with this session), and when I deploy the app in two devices I can do chat.

Is it good to create two different token for two users for the a session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenTok tokens can have different [permission level roles](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/create-token/) (ie. publisher, subscriber, moderator) which give them access to different features in the OpenTok Session. They also can have user data encoded in them as [connection data that shows up on the connection](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Classes/OTConnection.html#//api/name/data).

For this reason it usually makes sense to generate a different token for every user that grants them access to join a Session. If however both users have the same permissions and you're not encoding any user data in their token then I can't see a strong reason to require generating separate tokens. Other than you might want to add these things later. Keep in mind it's cheap to generate a token, it's just a hashing function that happens in your server, there is no API call or anything.